# How to get content from JComboBox from another class

Tags: java, android

i'm working on some app. on main page (register page) there is a combobox with few options to choose. Depend on what will be choose, specific content will apear in next window.
Question is how to getContent from this combobox which is in other class.

I assume that some if control instruction need to be added, but everytime i add something it returns an error.

Can someone please help how code should look like please ?
For example if option "1 " will be choosen , set background to Black, if "2" set background to Pink etc.

Register window:

```
public Main() throws Exception {

        registerWindowFrame = new JFrame("xxx");                                                    
        //registerWindowFrame.setSize(1440,2960);                                                                        
        registerWindowFrame.setSize(500, 750);
        registerWindowFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                                              
        registerWindowFrame.setLayout(null);
        registerWindowFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);

BloodList bloodList = new BloodList();
        bloodList.setSize(bloodList.getPreferredSize());
        bloodList.setLocation(10, 365);
        registerWindowFrame.add(bloodList);
```

comboxbox class:

```
public class BloodList extends JComboBox <String> {

    int i;

    public String[] bloodList =
            {
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",

            };

    public BloodList() {
        for (i=0; i < bloodList.length; i++)
        {
            this.addItem(bloodList[i]);
        };
    }

}
```

Window after regration window:

```
public mainWindowBplus() {
        super();
        bloodBplusFrame = new JFrame("SETTINGS");
        bloodBplusFrame.setSize(500, 750);
        bloodBplusFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        bloodBplusFrame.setLayout(null);
        bloodBplusFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    bloodBplusFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an `action listener` to you `jcombobox` which gets the value of the chosen `String` and then use that value in  the other class, try this:

```
public class BloodList extends JComboBox <String> {
    private String s="";

    private String[] bloodList =
            {
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",

            };

    public BloodList() {
        for (int i=0; i < bloodList.length; i++)
        {
            this.addItem(bloodList[i]);
        };
    }

    ActionListener cbActionListener = new ActionListener() {//add actionlistner to listen for change
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                s = (String) BloodList.this.getSelectedItem();//get the selected string
            }
    };

    this.addActionListener(cbActionListener);

    public String getS(){return s;}

}
```

Now you can use that `String` in another class by using the `getS()` method.

Comment: s = (String) date1.getSelectedItem(); - what "date1" means in that case, cause program underline this phrase as cannot resolve the symbol.

Comment: @TomaszKostrzewski i meant to write ```this```,I edited my answer.

Comment: if we change it to "this" than it says that cannot resolve the method...

Comment: Error:(34, 30) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: method getSelectedItem()

Comment: Try BloodList.this.getSelectedItem() instead of this.getSelectedItem()

Comment: perfect, it works. Can you advise why I should use structure of code like that ?

Comment: and how to use method getS() in other class now ... :/ cause when i try to do if(BloodList.getS() equals (something)) it's not working...

Comment: when an event happens(in your case the user select a/another value from the combobox) then it should be handled by an action listener or [item listener](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-itemlistener), this is the way to do it, now why did I make the ```String s``` private and you can access it via a get method instead of making it public, we'll this called encapsulation, this is basic OOP,you can find plenty of links explaining encapsulation (notice that i turned the ```String[] BloodList``` to private to instead of public)

Comment: you will be able to access it only if you initialized a ```BloodList Object``` in your class, for example in your ```Main``` you could write something like ```System.out.println{bloodList.getS();}``` if not, you can try to change the ```getS``` method to ```public static String getS(){return s;}``` instead of ```public String getS(){return s;}```

Comment: @TomaszKostrzewski let me know if it works with either of the above 2 methods that i stated.

Comment: But now i need to add something in cunstructor of BloodList bloodList = new BloodList(); in main class.

Comment: Error:(154, 31) java: constructor BloodList in class BloodList cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Where do you want to use that ```String s```? in which class?

Comment: you can always add the ```static``` keyword to the ```getS``` method: ```public static String getS(){return s;}```

Comment: @TomaszKostrzewski your welcome, also it would be great if you accept my answer as the correct one :)